# How to convert JSON Array to List<>?

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone

This is my json and I need to access the values under each object in the attendance array:

```
{"name":" ","course":"","attendance":[{"name":"INTERNATIONAL FINANCE","type":"Theory","conducted":"55","present":"50"},{"name":"INDIAN CONSTITUTION","type":"Theory","conducted":"6","present":"6"}]}
```

Here is my code:

```
public class Att
{

    public class Attendance
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string conducted { get; set; }
        public string present { get; set; }
    }


    public Att(string json)
    {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        JToken jUser = jObject;

        name = (string)jUser["name"];
        course = (string)jUser["course"];
        attender = jUser["attendance"].ToList<Attendance>;

    }

    public string name { get; set; }
    public string course { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    //public Array attend { get; set; }

    public List<Attendance> attender { get; set; }
}
```

It is the `attender = jUser["attendance"].ToList<Attendance>;` line that I have a problem with. It says,

> Cannot convert method group ToList to non-delegate type. Did you intend to invoke this method?

How do I access those values?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You have a typo!

> **attendance** vs **attendence**

And this should work

```
attender = jUser["attendance"].ToObject<List<Attendance>>();
```

You may find the running result at [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/497GZY)

Comment: But 'attendance' IS spelt with an 'a', not 'e'. :/

Answer (score 3):

You wanted to write:

```
attender = jUser["attendence"].ToList<Attendance>(); // notice the ()
```

---

**About the Error:**
When you dont put the parantheses there, C# assumes you want
to assign the function (delegate) `ToList` to the varaible `attender`, instead of
invoking it and assign its return value.

Comment: I agree with your answer but it is not satisfying the final question. **How do I access those values?** it throws _'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments_ using `ToObject<List<T>>()` will do the job.

Comment: CSharpie Thank you, sorry that was a stupid mistake. But the thing is I did try it with () and it threw the error @cilerler mentioned which I didn't notice as a different error. I eventually fixed it by converting it to 'List<JToken>' and accessing each of the string values in a for loop. Thank you once again CSharpie and cilerer. This is my first post at StackOverflow.